# Directive does not update on service model change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a service that contains my application's model:

```
angular.module('adminClient').factory('myApi', function () {
    var model = {};
    model.myObject = {
        label: 'New York City'
    };

    return {
        model: function () {
            return model;
        }
    };
});
```

A partial/controller has access to the model and can set a new myObject:

```
angular.module('adminClient').controller('MySelectNetworkCtrl', function ($scope, myApi) {

    $scope.myObject = myApi.model().myObject;

});
```

In addition to this, I have a directive that should display the label contained in myObject:

```
angular.module('nav').directive('myTopBar', function(myApi) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'nav/directive/my-top-bar/my-top-bar.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
            scope.myObject = myApi.model().myObject;
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="my-top-bar">
    <span ng-bind="myObject"></span>
</div>
```

When I run the application, the label is displayed fine (New York City), but as soon as the controller changes the myObject, the label in the directive remains unchanged. I can also see this in the Chrome Angular scope inspector.

Any idea how I can make the directive display the current value even after changed by the controller?

Comment: with a scope: {} definition in directive you are creating new isolated scope, try to remove it.

Comment: I tried setting scope to true, but this didn't help. IMHO, an isolated scope is what I need, as I am working with the service that contains all the data.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon how the controller is updating the model object. Since your code

`scope.myObject = myApi.model().myObject;`

gets hold of this specific model object it works fine as long as model object `myObject` properties are changed.

But if the controller does

`myApi.model().myObject= {};  //or any new object`

Now the model returned by service has different `myObject` and the directive one is different. Therefore changes do not work.

Instead in directive do:

`scope.myObject = myApi.model();  // bind to model`

And update the bindings in the directive template accordingly. See if it works

Comment: I understand what you are saying. However, this didn't work either. I now added    $scope.$watch('model.myObject', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.$apply();
    });
and it works, but now it also shows an error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress. Drives me nuts!

Comment: I definitely has something to do with the digest cycle not updating the model, as the value updates on the next digest cycle when I perfom some other clicks/actions. Not sure why it is not updating the model in the service. Any ideas?

Comment: If your watch is getting fired, you do not need to do scope.$apply in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BVDPSh6vxGWFlm97MyW0?p=preview)

If you want to modify your `myObject` inside your controller, and also want this change to be reflected inside your `my-top-bar` directive which then updates the directive's scope from `myApi` service, then you should do it like this.

Update the `myObject` in your controller and then also update it in your service through a setter method.

```
// Doing this will update your scope.myObject but 
// will not change the moObject in your service
$scope.myObject = {
  label: 'updated label'
};

// This will update your service, and anyone making a myApi.myApi.model() after this will get an updated myObject
myApi.setModel($scope.myObject);
// Notify directive of the change
$scope.$broadcast('updateDirective');
```

And in the factory:

```
angular.module('plunker').factory('myApi', function() {
  var model = {};
  model.myObject = {
    label: 'New York City'
  };

  return {
    model: function() {
      return model;
    },
    setModel: function(newModel) {
      model.myObject = newModel;
    }
  };
});
```

Finally, the directive:

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('myTopBar', function(myApi) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'top-bar.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
      console.log('in directive link', myApi.model().myObject);
      scope.myObject = myApi.model().myObject;
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.$on('updateDirective', function() {
        console.log('updating the scope of directive so that ng-bind works');
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.myObject = myApi.model().myObject;
          console.log($scope.myObject);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```